# Sys.executable is wrong - ModuleNotFound error

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I am new to programming and would appreciate help.

I had been running code successfully but recently installed conda, which is causing issues.

> Sys.executable shows 
>   C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\pythonw.exe
>   in IDLE and
>   C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe in
>   the command prompt.

However, when I run a script from my desktop calling sys.executable  in the command prompt, it shows `P:\conda\python.exe`. When I run other scripts from files on my desktop it also can no longer import modules, which are stored in the same folder as my original Python installation.

My question is: how can I change the interpreter for the files I am running from my desktop so that they can find the correct modules?

I have read all of StackOverflow's ModuleNotFound and `sys.executable` related threads but cannot fully understand what is going on - thanks for the help.

Comment: using conda and its navigator you have to create and select your environment. And then activate that environment which will be system wide. for example `conda create -n myenv python=3.6` and activate it. You can install your modules using `conda install package-name`

Comment: Right-click a .py script icon and selection open with and then choose another app. Choose the Python icon with a rocket on it (for the py.exe launcher) and enable the option to always use this app for .py files.

Comment: @eryksun I think your answer is on to something, but I accidentally hit "Command Prompt" when using "open with" and now when I click "open with" on any .py script, the box "always use this selected program" cannot be checked no matter what I choose.

Also, when I opened the py.exe launcher before this it gave me a warning that "this interpreter is in an anaconda environment but the environment has not been activated" so I'm not sure your workaround would have changed my sys.executable. Would appreciate any other thoughts.

Comment: I solved the "always use this program" issue using the first response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988880/set-python-idle-as-default-program-to-open-py-extensions 

Still trying to figure out how to switch to an interpreter not on Anaconda though, thanks

Comment: Hopefully you just reset the user choice instead of making IDLE the default. It's better to have editing with IDLE (or other IDEs) as a right-click action than as the primary action. As to virtual environments, the py.exe launcher may prefer an environment that's set in the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable, but otherwise it should only run regular PSF installations, not alternate distributions such as Anaconda. Run `py -0` to list available interpreters.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up solving this problem by typing the location of my original python installation (the desired sys.executable) before the name of the .py script I was looking to run. Not sure how to get back to this path being the default (I think it involves changing my path variable but don't want to mess anything up), though this works for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

create new python environment on conda as follows and run your code on new env:

Actually using conda and conda navigator is the better approach

After conda installation:
 - Open up the conda command prompt and create your working environment as follwos

```
conda create -n mytestenv python=3.7
```

Activate the environment:

```
conda activate mytestenv
```

Now, Run your code.

Later on if you need any module, Install your module using conda command on your selected environment, for example

```
conda install numpy
```

Comment: With the conda create command above I get a Conda HTTP Error. I can visit the Anaconda website in my browser just fine. I'm behind a proxy but when I type the proxy address that's worked for me in the past it returns an "unrecognized arguments" error. 
Also, is there any way to just go back to using the original (not Anaconda) interpreter?

Comment: I've solved the proxy issue with conda config --set proxy_servers.https https://address:port but please do let me know if there's a way to revert to the prior interpreter

Comment: Just create new environment for any python version of interpreter sit.